# Алгоритм получения комбинации по проценту (неограниченной длины)

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика, комбинаторика

Например есть следующая комбинация (все возможные комбинации из цифр от 1 до 2 длиной 3).

```
111 - 0%
112 - 14%
121 - 28%
122 - 42%
211 - 57%
212 - 71%
221 - 85%
222 - 100%
```

Комбинации цифр где каждая цифра может иметь диапазон в данном случае например от 1 до 2 включительно. Мне надо получить именно комбинацию 71% (например 71% эта комбинация 212 если кому не понятно).

Я в результате 1-го года размышлений как это можно сделать естественно не генерируя заранее готовые комбинации и выбирая из них уже по % я придумал алгоритм основанный на процентах от процентах но он не подходит для работы с большими по длине комбинациями (например 10000000 длина где цифры от 0 до 9 включительно), максимум комфортно это 300-1000 знаков, как бы он подходит, но для этого мне надо брать число процента с 0-ми равное по длине больше чем текста на этой странице и при нормализации по следующему % у меня уйдет n-е количество минут а то и часов.

Как получить по проценту любую комбинацию по ограничениям?

Comment: `(X-111).как бинарное число * 100/7` Ничего не понятно в вашем рассказе.

Comment: Ничего не понял... Вам нужна интерполяция? Или что?

Comment: У Вас комбинации, или все же числа? или как?

Comment: Ладно, может, кто понятливей меня найдется...

Comment: Я ничего не понимаю.

Comment: какие данные есть/что вводиться ? и что должно получиться в результате ?

Comment: Еще один раз поправил !

Comment: @Интик На входе я я подаю длину и процент, на выходе я получаю комбинацию (порядок цифр) Так работает мой алгоритм но он мне не подходит.

Comment: А что тут год думать? заменяем цифры на 01...n, получаем все числа в n-1-чной системе счисления, и все. 71%? Без вопросов. для вашего случая всего 8 значений, значит, 0.71*7 ~5? значит, 101, или, по-вашему, 212. На что вы потратили год?

Comment: С системами счисления не походит, есть погрешность при больший размерах и работы с точными значениями.

Comment: @ПавелБиза , в любом случае на алфавите `1`, `2` для 50% ответом будет `2111...111`. Эта комбинация средняя по номеру, что соответствует среднему проценту. Если вы думаете по-другому и рассчитываете на понимание, то вам следует объясниться.

Comment: Вот результаты которые тут код человек скидывал снизу на python. (https://ibb.co/DCL0XX7 https://ibb.co/bLDPZxL https://ibb.co/5LHW4t9) (43,51,67%) да, красивый сдвиг есть, но все одинаково, не может быть такого что бы в таком переводе все учитывалось, мой алгоритм по процентно разбивает все учитывая предыдущее состояние, что и делает возможным получения любой  комбинации по проценту, числа получаются абсолютно не повторяющимися, а это не подходит, сплошная повторяющиеся сосиска на разных процентах, разве такое может быть на таких процентах ?!

Comment: Да, такое может и должно быть. Двоичные (и десятичные и любые) дроби рациональных чисел - периодические. Длина периода зависит в том числе от количества цифр в проценте. Для 71 период будет не длинным, для 71.2 длиннее. Для 71.23456789 период может быть очень длинным.

Comment: @ПавелБиза, у вас ловко получаются картинки. Сделайте, пожалуйста, картинку для `71.23456789`.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy https://ibb.co/KsByR4g вроде как для 71.23456789 печально, но такие изображения я получал и просто беря корень из квадрата любого числа, если среднее изображение из всех это только 1-ы в двоичном представлении то это ПЕЧАЛЬКА. Ты можешь его еще размыть по гауссу и присмотреться.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132042/discussion-between-stanislav-volodarskiy-and--).

Answer (score 1):

Попробую накидать схему на Вашем примере.
Трехсимвольные комбинации из цифр 1 и 2. Таких комбинаций всего 8.

1. Считаем, сколько процентов составляет одна комбинация. `c=100/7`
2. Имея проценты, например, 71%,находим номер этой комбинации `n = 71/c`, номера начинаются с нуля.
3. Так как используются только две цифры, переводим полученный номер в двоичную запись и представляем строкой.
4. каждую цифру в строке увеличиваем на значение младшей используемой цифры - в вашем случае на 1. А если бы использовались, например, цифры 6 и 7, то увеличивали бы на 6.
5. Результат получен.

Кажется, должно работать...

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132023/discussion-on-answer-by--------).

Answer (score 1):

А что тут год думать? заменяем цифры в порялке возрастания на 01...n, получаем все числа в n-1-чной системе счисления, и все.

71%? Без вопросов. Для вашего случая всего 8 значений, значит, так как 0 соотетствует 0%, диапазон равен 7 значений.

0.71*7 ~5? значит, 5 == 101, или, по-вашему, 212. На что вы потратили год?

Для 123 - тут может быть всего 3^3=27 значений, значит, 0.71*(27-1) = 18.46. Округляем до 18, в троичной системе счисления это 200, значит, переводя в ваши цифры, 311.

Comment: Изначально это рассматривал, но не так глубоко. У меня другой подход, придаться все это обдумывать и совмещать для чего все это и надо. Только вчера подумал заново этим заняться.

Comment: Все же это мне не подходит, для размеров в 1166400 хотябы это как по мне для 256 бит без decimal не реально. А с decimal что тут пример приводили, нужно правильное prec значение, и оно не спасает. Короче это unreal сделать. Всегда будут ограничения.

Comment: У вас ведь python в метках — а уж он-то с длинной целочисленной арифметикой справляется на ура...

Answer (score 0):

На степень `b` умножаем, округляем, `b`-ичную запись получаем.

Функция `to_digits` переводит число в цифры по заданной базе. Питон не поддерживает эту функциональность из коробки. Для скорости пришлось сделать "разделяй и властвуй":

```
def to_digits(k, n, b):

    def digits(k, n):
        if n <= 256:
            for _ in range(n):
                yield 1 + k % b
                k //= b
        else:
            n1 = n // 2
            n2 = n - n1
            k2, k1 = divmod(k, b ** n1)
            yield from digits(k1, n1)
            yield from digits(k2, n2)

    return reversed(tuple(digits(k, n)))


t1, t2, t3 = input().split()
n = int(t1)
b = int(t2)
p = float(t3)
pn, pd = p.as_integer_ratio()

m = b ** n - 1
k = (m * pn + (100 * pd) // 2) // (100 * pd)

sep = '' if b < 10 else '_'
print(sep.join(str(d) for d in to_digits(k, n, b)))
```

> ```
> $ echo 3 2 71 | python strange-percents.py
> 212
>
> $ echo 3 3 71 | python strange-percents.py
> 311
>
> $ echo 3 9 71 | python strange-percents.py
> 745
>
> $ echo 3 10 71 | python strange-percents.py
> 8_1_10
>
> $ time echo 1166400 2 71 | python strange-percents.py
> 2122121222...1111212111
>
> real  0m2.152s
> user  0m2.076s
> sys   0m0.020s
>
> $ time echo 1166400 2 86 | python strange-percents.py
> 2212221111...2121112222
>
> real  0m2.166s
> user  0m2.076s
> sys   0m0.032s
> ```

Comment: Вот это не подходит, мне нужно работать хотя бы с такими длинами 1660000. Придеться подключать decimal, и то не вариант, таких объёмов у меня не хватить ил хватить, скоро проверю.

Comment: Добавил поддержку больших `n`.

Comment: При разных процентах (71 и 86) и длины 1166400 выдает абсолютно одинаковые ретмические цифры, а на 50 и меньше вообще 1-ы. Это сделать не возможно все же. Придеться свой переделывать или реально использовать цифры с размером unreal использую decimal.

Comment: При 50 должно быть число в ответе: `211....111`. Это правильный ответ. Для 71 и 86 ответы разные.

Comment: Добавил поддержку произвольных баз.

Comment: Специально для тебя ! (https://ibb.co/DCL0XX7 https://ibb.co/bLDPZxL https://ibb.co/5LHW4t9) (43,51,67%) да, красивый сдвиг есть, но все одинаково, не может быть такого что бы в таком переводе все учитывалось, мой алгоритм по процентно разбивает все учитывая предыдущее состояние, а это не подходит !

Comment: @ПавелБиза, то что мы строим - двоичная дробь. Все двоичные дроби рациональных чисел - периодические. Вот [обсужденние для десятичных дробей](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8C#%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8). То что вы видите периодический узор - закон природы. Узор будет простым если в проценте будет мало цифр, узор будет усложняться если задать в проценте больше цифр.

Comment: "Основное свойство периодических дробей, благодаря которому их выделяют из всей совокупности десятичных дробей, заключается в том, что периодические дроби и только они представляют рациональные числа."

Comment: @ПавелБиза, не сложно написать программу которая по данному проценту выведет период который будет повторяться во всех достаточно длинных последовательностях. На этом сайте ищите "период десятичной дроби".

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132041/discussion-between-stanislav-volodarskiy-and--).